# How to delete all data from neo4j-sandbox?

Tags: database, neo4j

I am currently working with the neo4j sandbox and have a lot of nodes and relationships.

Now that I want to begin a new project and delete all those old nodes/relationships etc. - I can't find a "delete all"- or "reset"-Button.

Does anybody of you know how I can reset (delete all data stored online in) the sandbox?

Thank you for you answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cypher for this is

```
 MATCH (n)
 DETACH DELETE n;
```

DETACH DELETE is because a node must not have any relation for it to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher query above suggested by @jerome-b is perfect if you have small dataset but isn't enough for large amounts of data, see [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/delete/#delete-delete-all-nodes-and-relationships).

> This query isn’t for deleting large amounts of data, but is nice when
>   playing around with small example data sets.

So, try this:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 10000
DETACH DELETE n
RETURN count(*)
```

Run this until the statement returns 0 (zero) records. From the Official Neo4j documentation, they describe it as a best practice: [Large Delete Transaction Best Practices in Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/large-delete-transaction-best-practices-in-neo4j/).